# Using javamail to append messages to Yahoo "Sent" folder?

Tags: java, android, smtp, jakarta-mail

Currently I have this going on:

```
Store store = sendsession.getStore(mailhost);
   store.connect(mailhost, user, password);
   String box = "SENT";
   Folder folder = store.getFolder(box);
   folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
   message.setFlag(Flag.SEEN, true);
   folder.appendMessages(new Message[] {message});
   store.close();
```

And it works for Gmail and Hotmail, but it wont send to the Sent folder when sending from Yahoo. Is the sent folder accessed by a different name in yahoo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard or universal name for the "Sent" folder.  It's a convention of the mail client you're using; different clients might follow different conventions.

Also, see [this JavaMail wiki entry on Yahoo Mail](http://kenai.com/projects/javamail/pages/Yahoo).

If that doesn't help, [this JavaMail FAQ entry explains the additional information we need to help you debug the problem](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug).